# android gridview dynamically add item but face duplicate image

Tags: android, android-gridview

i used android gridview, and i dynamically add item to imageAdapter, but duplicate image items was displayed.I used ViewHolder to process each grid.
here is my getView code:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_product_image, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
        viewHolder.iv_image.setId(position);
        viewHolder.iv_delete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_delete);
        viewHolder.rl_grid = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_grid);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(mImages.get(position) instanceof ParseFile) {
        int orientation = 0;
        try {
            orientation = Exif.getOrientation(((ParseFile)mImages.get(position)).getData());
        }catch(ParseException pe){
            Log.e("read Exif error", pe.getMessage());
        }
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(((ParseFile)mImages.get(position)).getUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.img_loading)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .rotate(orientation)
                .into(viewHolder.iv_image);

    }else if(mImages.get(position) instanceof byte[]){
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray((byte[])mImages.get(position), 0, ((byte[]) mImages.get(position)).length);
            viewHolder.iv_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: can there be an else clause too? if so, you should mention that, and also use display image through picasso only in all of your clauses.

Comment: @SarthakMittal i want to make a product images editor which allows user to  upload images and choose image to delete, so i load images from cloud (display through picasso). And user also could choose image from their device or take pictures to upload, so this ImageAdapter need to show both througn picasso and bitmap.

Comment: from where are you getting the byte array? is it from some uri or stream?